# How do we can Access to Payload of Received Packets in DPDK 18.11.9

Tags: c, dpdk

I am running `dpdk-stable-18.11.9` on `Ubuntu 18.04`.I have external card that was generating  `UDP` packet continuously (rate:40Gbps) I want to receive packets in single port NIC (ConnectX®-4 Lx EN 10/25/40/50GbE Ethernet Adapter Cards Single port).

I saw `skeleton` example in `DPDK SDK` and used `rte_eth_rx_burst(port_id,queue_id,pkts_burst, MAX_PKT_BURST)` function to receive packets.In Debugging mode I can see property in `pkts_burst`,But I can not access to Packets Payload.

How can I access to packets payload?Which funtion help me?

Answer (score 2):

In order to access a received packet's ethernet payload use DPDK API [rte_pktmbuf_mtod()](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__mbuf__core_8h.html#a2a8b10263496c7b580e9d0c7f2a1f073).

```
    for (i = 0; i < nb_rx; i++) {
        /* access payload of rcv'd pkt at ethernet header */
        eth_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(pkt, struct ether_hdr *);
    }
```

but if the intention is more than just ethernet header, you can refer to below sample code snippet for ipv4.

```
#include <linux/if_vlan.h>
```

In the main processing loop

```
uint16_t i, nb_rx, len;
uint16_t ether_type;
struct ether_hdr *eth_hdr;
struct vlan_hdr *vh;
uint16_t *proto;
struct ipv4_hdr *ip_hdr;
struct rte_mbuf *pkts_burst[MAX_PKT_BURST];

/* rcv burst of pkts from interface, on success returns no. of pkts rcv'd  */
nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port_id, queue_id, pkts_burst, MAX_PKT_BURST)

/* Loop through rcv'd pkts */
for (i = 0; i < nb_rx; i++) {
    /* update len on each iteration to 0 */
    len = 0;

    /* access payload of rcv'd pkt at ethernet header */
    eth_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(pkts_burst[i], struct ether_hdr *);

    if (rte_cpu_to_be_16(ETHER_TYPE_VLAN) == eth_hdr->ether_type) {
        len = sizeof(struct ether_hdr);
        vh = (struct vlan_hdr *)(eth_hdr + 1);

        proto = vh->eth_proto;
        if (rte_cpu_to_be_16(ETHER_TYPE_VLAN) == *proto) {
            len += sizeof(struct vlan_hdr);
            proto = vh->eth_proto;
        }

         /* free up non ipv4 packets */
         if (rte_cpu_to_be_16(ETHER_TYPE_IPv4) != *proto)
             rte_pktmbuf_free(pkt);
    }

    /* access IP header of rcv'd pkt */
    ip_hdr = (struct ipv4_hdr *)(rte_pktmbuf_mtod(pkts_burst[i], char *) + len);   

    /* process packets which are ipv4 */
}
```

Comment: @Vipin Varghese, thanks for the edit, in fact I have the same idea but wanted to keep it simple for OPs understanding.

Comment: good to hear from you. Based on skype interaction with Ali (@Alexanov) has homegrown solution from his team which works on raw socket. To scale he is searching the minimal changes to be done in an example file of DPDK to make it work. Hence `I saw skeleton example in DPDK SDK and used rte_eth_rx_burst(port_id,queue_id,pkts_burst, MAX_PKT_BURST) function to receive packets.` means `what I must do minimum to make it work`.

Comment: @SunilBojanapally, Thank you for your answer,it was helpful for me.But I want to access the packet payload completely that was include `eth_hdr+Ip_hdr+udp_hdr+udp_payload` from `pkts_burst[0]`.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I want to access `pkts_burst[0]` with all headers . How can I do that?

Comment: @SunilBojanapally and myself have given you the code and access point clearly. Please explain your question clearly.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Thank you, Your solution is very good but my problem still remain. I have `pkts_burst[MAX_PKT_BURST]` and I want to access `pkts_burst[0]`(that was include  `eth_hdr+Ip_hdr+udp_hdr+udp_payload` =1512 byte ). how can I see  data of `pkts_burst[0]` (all 1512 byte frame of data together not split)

Comment: @Alexanov looks like you want C or CPP code to access ether. Ip, udp and payload. This is different question, So please open a new one. :)