# How to access various layers in a packet received via DPDK?

Tags: c, dpdk

I am running `dpdk-stable-18.11.9` on `Ubuntu 18.04`. I used `rte_eth_rx_burst(port_id,queue_id,pkts_burst, MAX_PKT_BURST)` function to receive packets.

I want to access the various headers of packet namely `eth_hdr+Ip_hdr+udp_hdr+udp_payload` for valid `pkts_burst[0]`.

For example, in Wireshark I can show you what I need from pkts_burst[0].

[image]

ALL 1512 BYTE LIKE RED SECTION INSERT ON 1512 BYTE ARRAY :

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: @VipinVarghese please help me :)

Comment: please share your current code logic which accesses the packet headers

Comment: I believe I have explained the reason of downvote. Please also refer to [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289631/random-downvoting-for-no-reason] and [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152174/how-to-deal-with-downvotes-without-any-explanation#:~:text=Sometimes%20there%20are%20bad%20questions,edit%20and%20improve%20the%20question.]. Please do share your sample code that is not working for you, I am most happy to check and suggest what is going wrong. If the requirement is for working code from scratch please use `freelancer.com or upwork.com`

Comment: I humbly request to check comment from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63392719/how-do-we-can-access-to-payload-of-received-packets-in-dpdk-18-11-9/63398611?noredirect=1#comment112189048_63398611 Before criticizing or blaming the facts or people. I hope you will share your sample code for us to review, if not you will be opening a request in `StackOverflow as bountied` or in `up work or freelancer` for code from scratch.

Comment: @Alexanov All you get is the bytes. Wireshark does the work to figure out what the bytes mean, and you can too. I suggest you research these protocols, and how packet headers work.

Comment: even though the issue is recognized and solution is provided, https://stackoverflow.com/users/690017/andre-hofmeister believes to reject the changes with the reasoning `This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.`

Comment: same is the case with https://stackoverflow.com/users/8242447/%e1%b9%82%c5%b3%e1%bb%bb%e1%bb%8bg%c7%bb%c5%88%e1%ba%a1c%e1%bb%83%c6%a1%e1%bb%ad%e1%b9%a9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [How do we can Access to Payload of Received Packets in DPDK 18.11.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63392719/how-do-we-can-access-to-payload-of-received-packets-in-dpdk-18-11-9/63398611#63398611) as reference code for accessing the payload till IPv4 header. then access the UDP layer by

```
#include <rte_udp.h>
```

inside process function

```
struct udp_hdr *udp = (struct udp_hdr *)((unsigned char *)ipv4_hdr +                                      
 sizeof(struct ipv4_hdr));
unsigned char *paylaod = (unsigned char *) (udp + 1);
```

note: UDP header and UDP payload right after IP header.

P.S. had spent separate skype calling in explaining and making sure the information is shared.